# TCPTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63 in WSO2

Tags: xml, wso2

I use WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2 to create API, and generate a Docker image (MI 4.0.0). But when I try to run the container, something like this happens:

```
2023-11-03 23:59:56 [2023-11-03 16:59:56,933]  INFO {EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Logging configuration changed. (Event Admin service unavailable - no notification sent).
2023-11-03 23:59:58 [2023-11-03 16:59:58,282] FATAL {CoreServerInitializer} - WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from /home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:181)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:66)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.CoreServerInitializer.initializeCarbon(CoreServerInitializer.java:208)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.CoreServerInitializer.initMIServer(CoreServerInitializer.java:125)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:82)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
2023-11-03 23:59:58 Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.synapse.transport.netty.sender.Axis2HttpTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:718)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:125)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:312)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:179)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     ... 23 more
2023-11-03 23:59:58 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.transport.netty.sender.Axis2HttpTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:692)
2023-11-03 23:59:58     ... 26 more
2023-11-03 23:59:58
```

I have tried to find the answer, but no avail. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Which docker base image are you using? It seems it's corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The docker exporter is quite faulty, so I download dockerfile from the wso 2 git and build it myself. Problem solved!
https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/tree/master/dockerfiles/ubuntu/micro-integrator